# How to join BigQuery table with ADH(Ads Data Hub) table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-data-hub, ads-data-hub, python-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table 'A' with schema `{'UUID': 'String'}`. I want to join this table with a ADH(Ads Data Hub) table 'B' having schema `{'UUID': 'String', 'USER_ID': 'INT'}` on UUID and fetch all `user_ids` to a new table.

I am having trouble in joining ADH table with BigQuery table.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Any chance you could provide us with what you've tried so far i.e. your SQL?

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley, right now I've created table in BigQuery in GoLang. The issue I am facing is how do I join my BQ table with ADH table. I don't know where to start with. ADH - https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/intro

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to try with [Google Ads transfers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer) which allows you to automatically schedule and manage recurring load jobs for Google Ads reporting data. Once you have your data in BigQuery you can use the [Google Ads sample queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer#google_ads_sample_queries) as a reference to  to analyze your transferred data.

Using the [BigQuery client library for GO](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#running_queries) you will get more information about  how to run your query with the join desired.

Answer (score 0):

If your table A locates in the same region as your ADH account, you should be able to run cross table queries in ADH.
You cannot query user_id as part of the output by using ADH, it's not allowed due to privacy protection. However, if you had your UUID passed to Google Marketing Platform using floodlight with custom-variable enabled, you can use this UUID as join key to map both tables, and do analysis from there.